# How to get past a damaging floor in skyrim on the darkness rises quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

To be plain I am stuck or I took a wrong turn somewhere. If I took a wrong turn please put me on the right path. If that is not the case than how do you get past the floor because I cannot go more than ten steps without dying a horrorful painful death. Please help a nocturnal brother.

Comment: There is a Skyrim tag, please use that for any Skyrim related questions

Comment: A nocturnal needs help

Answer (score 4):

Paraphrased from http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Returns

You need to sneak through the darkness, avoiding the light, and avoiding standing up.